# Spring MVC + Thymeleaf: How to use multiple Formatters / Converters for the same object?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am using Spring MVC (4.2.3) + Thymeleaf (2.1.4). I use the default Spring Boot configuration that registers Converters and Formatters through WebMvcAutoConfiguration.

I have created a few Spring Converter beans for different objects. I would like to use the formatting capabilities in Thymeleaf with the double-bracket syntax like this example:

```
<td th:text="${{model.foo}}">Default Foo</td>
```

Then let's say I have:

```
public class ConverterA implements Converter<Foo, String> {...}
public class ConverterB implements Converter<Foo, String> {...}
public class ConverterC implements Converter<Foo, String> {...}
```

How do I specify which Converter I want to use in the Thymeleaf view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have multiple possibilities, I think you'll have to explicitly use one. You can use the Thymeleaf ability to use Spring beans by name to do something like this:

```
th:text="${@converterB.convert(foo)}"
```